# Meaning of "Use was made of something"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

I found, in many literature, that a sentence has been started with "Use was made of". The complete sentence is like this:  "Use was made of something"

What does it actually mean?

Comment: Related: [To use vs to make use of: when to use what](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/to-use-vs-make-use-of-when-to-use-what).

Answer (score 2):

It's just another way of saying

> Something was used ...

In the above sentence, "used" is used as a verb. This sentence is in the active voice.

Whereas in the sentence in the question,

> Use was made of something ...

"use" is used as a noun and the sentence is in the passive voice.

For a more elaborate explanation on active and passive voice, you can look up [this guide from British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/active-and-passive-voice).

Answer (score 0):

***Make use of*** is a transitive multi-word verb of the verbo-nominal class, is commonly used, and is often a more formal replacement for 'use'. It does also  carry the sense of 'find something helpful / useful / convenient / fitting'.

*We made good use of the money you gave us.*

*Make sense of* is a similar MWV, but is resistant to passivisation

(??/* *Sense was made of the instructions.*)

Here,

*Use was made of the ropes from the wreck in the building of a raft.*

is far more acceptable.

Comment: I disagree that *make use of* is considered "more" formal, except by those who have mistakenly learned that verbosity imbues formality. Not my DV, by the way.